# Does imitation of standard iOS UI elements lead to rejection in app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'm working on an iOS shopping app where users are shown a popup where they can choose to proceed to checkout as guest or login if they are registered. The design requires the popup to expand to show the password field if the user wants to login (otherwise only the email id field is shown so that he can proceed as guest). If users enter invalid email id or leave a field blank, the popup is required to expand further so that the users can be notified near the fields.

The only issue is, the design is such that this whole popup has the color, gradient and animation of UIAlertView, including the buttons. And as the normal UIAlertView can't be used to provide such extended functions, I designed it myself (as a view) and I'm presenting it modally with animations so that it looks like a UIAlertView has appeared

I just wanted to know whether this kind of imitation could lead to my app being rejected in the app store.

Comment: I would not think so.  It is called innovation.  But then who can predict!

Comment: For what reason do you believe your app would get rejected?

Comment: @Popeye, I think it's pretty clear in the last sentence of my question :)

Comment: That sentence doesn't make it clear at all why you think it would get rejected. The only reason your app would get reject is if you were subclassing `UIAlertView`. Are you subclassing `UIAlertView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of components that mimic or extend the Apple components, for example: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch

With regards to your UIAlertView approach - there are loads of customized UIAlertViews on github as well, and these have been used in many apps, such as this one: https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog . .nothing out of the ordinary here.

As long as you conform to the Human Interface Guidelines with regards to sizing etc, it will be OK.

I can see another problem with your App, however. Apple will reject an application from the App store that excludes users, or is only usable by a specific group of users. So if you provide a sign-on feature, it needs to be easy for the user to sign-up (freely) or provide guest access.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JasperBlues. The app does provide an easy guest access :)

Answer (score 1):

May be:

**App Store Review Guidelines**

**10. User Interface**

**10.3** Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines may be rejected

See these docs:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: So far, i haven't used any system provided items "incorrectly". I have only imitated the look of a particular item and given it some extended functions as required by my app. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand Apple's guidelines they don't want you to use familiar UI elements in suprising ways thereby confusing the users.

By correctly imitating UI elements, you are not confusing the user (as he/she probably can't tell the difference between the native and imitated implementation). So I don't expect them to reject your app.

However, you will have more work to adapt your app to the upcoming iOS 7 design and in particular to create an app that concurrently supports the iOS 6 and iOS 7 look (which will be the reality for some time).